# Jquery Ajax call needs a pause?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem calling an ajax command.. So the problem is that after the ajax has called the php page (and after having inserted the data in the db).. the success of the ajax call should redirect the page somewhere else.... this is the code:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "insertInfo.php",
     timeout: 3000,
     data: "name=" + myName + "&email=" + myEmail + 
               "&birthdate=" + myBirthdate + "&nickname=" + 
               myNickName + "&shirtcolor=" + myShirtColor + "&slogancolor=" +
               mySloganColor + "&slogantext=" + mySloganText,
         success: function(data)
         {
          if(data.operation=="completed")
          {
            window.location.href = "thank_you.php";
          }         
         }
});
```

Now the strange thing happens when I put :

```
alert('test')
```

Before calling the ajax!.. If I put it, of course the messagebox appears, the ajax works perfectly, connecting to the db and redirecting the page.

If I take away the alert box, nothing happens, the database is not modified and no redirect happens.

I don't understand where could be the problem... Do I have to furnish some pause to the ajax call?.

Thnak you a lot for every sane explanation :)

---

if ($('.info-user-form').valid())
                {

```
                var myShirtColor = $('input[name="shirt"]').val();
                var mySloganText = $('input[name="shirtText"]').val();
                var mySloganColor = $('input[name="slogan"]').val();

                var myName = $('input#name').val();
                var myEmail = $('input#email').val();
                var myBirthdate = $('input#birthdate').val();
                var myNickName = $('input#nickname').val();



                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "insertInfo.php",
                    timeout: 3000,
                    data: "name=" + myName + "&email=" + myEmail + "&birthdate=" + myBirthdate + "&nickname=" + myNickName + "&shirtcolor=" + myShirtColor + "&slogancolor=" + mySloganColor + "&slogantext=" + mySloganText,
                    success: function(data){                                                        
                        if(data.operation=="completed")
                        {                               
                            window.location.href = "thank_you.php";
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
```

Ok, so this is inside a document.ready of jquery.... 
all of it... ht eonly difference is the presence o fthe alertbox before the ajax call in one case... 
Thank you all for your responses, i'll try to look at the bugzilla, even if i don't know what tot expect....

---

Made the test also with firebug...

So, with firebug running, the jax will save the data in the db and will redirect the page.
Witgh firebug close, will just save the data, without redirecting

In Chrome not even saving data....

Comment: where do you put the `alert(test)`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Try to set the whole call inside a $(document).ready(function (){...do call...})

Comment: Gideon: i put the alert test before the ajax call...

Comment: Rory: i can't see any...

Comment: Simon: it should be iokay like the code... i mean, it works with the alert box...

Answer (score 1):

```
var queryString = "name=" + myName + "&email=" + myEmail + 
           "&birthdate=" + myBirthdate + "&nickname=" + 
           myNickName + "&shirtcolor=" + myShirtColor + "&slogancolor=" +
           mySloganColor + "&slogantext=" + mySloganText"";

data : queryString
```

Try to add this.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
type:'GET',
```

And get your values on insertInfo.php Using `$_GET`

For redirection add this code in your success function

```
var url = "thank_you.php";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Its worked

Answer (score 0):

Check your error console and network log to see what's going on. Also a possible cause is that you are trying to grab input values etc from the DOM before it's initialised. If that were the case you could put your code inside $(document).ready event. Hope this helps

Comment: but if i put an alertbox with the string of values get from DOM (the ones that i should send trhough ajax to the db), the string is correct.... it seems that the alert box slow eveyrthing down and the ajax can works correctly...

Comment: Does Firebug show that the request went through or was it cancelled? Does your server/code use gzip compression on the returned data? Try disabling that if so. Are you using the latest version of JQuery? Make sure you are.

Answer (score 0):

so after searching and various tests I found out that if i put the option

async: false

in the ajax calls,

it works perfectly (I'll test in firefox, in chrome works perfectly.. )..

Anyone does understand why?... it would be nice to know.... thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are validating a form. Make sure that your listener of form submission returns false

Comment: It does... otherwise I think it wouldn't work neither with the alertBox before the ajax call.. But i wouls really like to know the reason why it does work applying the async: false condition...

Comment: does someting happen when you place alert('inside'); after window.location.href = "thank_you.php"; ?